# SQL Server authentication connection string outside of connectionstring node in app.config

Tags: .net, sql-server, connection-string

I've inherited an old Winforms app that's set up a little differently than I'm used to. The app has two connection strings but they're not stored in the `<connectionStrings>` element in the `web.config`.

They're set up as follows:

```
<setting name="sqlTrainingConnectString" serializeAs="String">
    <value>Data Source=RPT10000012;initial catalog=TEST_RPTDatabase;integrated security=True;</value>
</setting>

<setting name="sqlConnectString" serializeAs="String">
    <value>Data Source=RPT10000012;initial catalog=LIVE_RPTDatabase;integrated security=True;</value>
</setting>
```

These are pointing to local DBs and I'm trying to get them to connect to a remote DB server using:

```
<setting name="sqlConnectString" serializeAs="String">
    <value>Data Source=TY097326.corp.company.com;Database=TEST_RPTDatabase;Integrated Security=False;User Id=WebUser; password=somePass;</value>
</setting>

<setting name="sqlTrainingConnectString" serializeAs="String">
    <value>Data Source=TY097326.corp.company.com;Database=LIVE_RPTDatabase;Integrated Security=False;User Id=WebUser; password=somePass;</value>
</setting>
```

but I'm getting an error

> A network-related or instance specific server occurred while establishing a connection

I've never tried to store the connection string like this before and I'm not sure I have it set up right. I can connect fine from my local SSMS, and have execute permissions, but can't get this to punch through in the code.

Comment: can you share the stack trace? and one other info: I am editing your post to set your password. I am fearing you have shared original pass by accident.

Comment: Remove the "Integrated Security" section completely.

Comment: I stubbed in test data for the server name, userID, and password so don't worry about changing it.

Comment: Make sure you getting the correct connection string right before you use it, check with your debugger. Also, can you confirm you can reach `TY097326.corp.company.com` from your workstation?

Comment: Well, since it's a **Winforms** application (desktop application), it will have an `app.config` configuration - not a `web.config` (that's for **web** - not desktop - applications)

Comment: Right, meant app.config.

Comment: Are those <settings> tag under <configuration> tag?

Comment: I moved this to a test web application but I'm getting the same error. So now it's in the connectionString element under the configuration tag.

Comment: As it turns out, I was given the wrong connectionString.  Thanks to everyone that commented.